# Python: How to call and run python scripts from desktop by giving command in python editor?

Tags: python

I have two python script files in my desktop folder and I would like to run based on if statement. For example: If calling 'Ram' and 'Sam' then run python script file_1 and for 'Mohan' run python script file_2. Is there any way where I can call and run the scripts by giving some command based on if statement? Below is the path of files and dataframe.

```
file_1 = 'c:/users/rec/name/file_1.py'
file_2 = 'c:/users/rec/name/file_2.py'

df = {'name': ['Ram','Mohan','Sam'], 'salary':[1000, 2000, 1500]}
```

Comment: You can look into the `os` library for running arbitrary system commands (including running other python scripts) from python. Much better would be to structure your project in such as way as to be able to import those two files as modules. Perhaps better still (depending on the complexity of those two files) : why not just bring them into the file where your df is defined, as functions instead, taking the name as an argument ?

Comment: Sure. I will look at it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an import statement to run:

- First, name the file you showed us as `'c:/users/rec/name/<filename>.py'`
- Next, try running this:

```
df = {'name': ['Ram','Mohan','Sam'], 'salary':[1000, 2000, 1500]}

person = 'Ram' #Get somebody in this variable

#Import each program depending on person
if person == 'Ram' or person == 'Sam':
    import file_1

else if person == 'Mohan':
    import file_2

else:
    print('Person was not Sam, Ram, or Mohan.')

#Adjust as needed
```

To rename a file, use `os.rename`:

```
import os

os.rename('original file name', 'new file name')
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I will check and get back very soon. Hope it works. Thanks.

Comment: Importing doesn't just get the functions from modules like `numpy` or `os` or `tensorflow`. It runs the code in the module. The modules that you typically `import` don't do anything, they just define variables and functions.

Comment: I agree. I also have a output program in the above scripts which get save in directory. It means once I run the above script, I should see the output in directory.

Comment: Mark this answer as the best answer by clicking the checkmark below it.

Comment: One last thing. how to name the files ...like we use pd.read_csv to read csv files. What convention we use to read the file or any additional libraries to import?

Comment: Hi..Please suggest how to name the file. Because it is showing me error.

Comment: Done! Use `os.rename` as specified in the post.